# XPath not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0, xpath

I have an XML document in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SupportedServices>
  <Service>
    <name>Google Weather</name>
    <active>Yes</active>
  </Service>
   ...
</SupportedServices>
```

And I'm trying to parse the XML file like so:

```
public void InitializeDropDown(string XmlFile, string xpath)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(XmlFile);

    var rootNode = doc.DocumentElement;

    var serviceList = rootNode.SelectNodes(xpath);

    Parallel.ForEach(serviceList.Cast<XmlNode>(), service =>
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.ServiceActive &&
            Properties.Settings.Default.ServiceName == service.InnerText)
        {
            WeatherServicesCBO.Items.Add(service.InnerText);
        }
    });
}
```

The issue I'm having is both values (name & active) are selected so it would look like **Google WeatherYes**, when All I'm wanting is **Google Weather**. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my XPath (which is here):

```
InitializeDropDown("SupportedWeatherServices.xml", "descendant::Service[name]");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XPath should be `//Service/name`

```
var serviceList = rootNode.SelectNodes("//Service/name");
```

or `descendant::Service/name`, if you like this syntax more.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it works beautiful. ut technically what was wrong with my original xpath?

Comment: `Service[name]` selects a Service provided that it has a name child. `Service/name` selects the name child.